# Iterate with LINQ over a list and set founded varible

Tags: c#, linq, iteration

I have this code and want to do the same with a linq statement.

```
foreach (var field in fieldExtension)
     {
          if (field.Name.Equals(item.Name))
          {
                field.Access = true;
          }
     }
```

It is easy to iterate over the list with:

```
fieldExtension.Where(field => field.Name.Equals(item.Name));
```

But is it posible to assign a value to the variable we have found in the list? I thought about something like this:

```
fieldExtension.Where(field => field.Name.Equals(item.Name)).Select(field => field.Access = true);
```

Does anybody know a way to do it correctly with linq? Because I don't want to split it up. Which would also work.

```
var result = fieldExtension.Where(field => field.Name.Equals(item.Name)).ToList();
result.FirstOrDefault().Access = true;
```

Comment: fieldExtension.Where(field => field.Name.Equals(item.Name)).ToList().ForEach(field => field.Access = true);

Comment: Interessting aproach, but it seems a bit like a hack. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you insist on linq? its not a good practice to use linq alll the time.

How ever you can mix linq with foreach.

```
foreach (var field in fieldExtension.Where(f => f.Name.Equals(item.Name)))
{
    field.Access = true;
}
```

Comment: In my company they prevere linq because of the readability and i wanted to know where the limits of linq are. but I think I will go with this mix.